# AsyncTask textview redrawing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, refresh

I am a little bit beginner with Android, and I cannot explain one things with my code.

I have a TextView and a Button on my activity. On a button Click I start my AsyncTask child class giving my activity instance to its constructor. This long running asynctask updates my textview in the progress update, but during this the textView is not cleared and completely redrawn, instead the numbers are written on top of each other.

It is not important why I solved this async for now, as it is a part of a test, the only interesting question for me right now is that why happens this. Have I forget an important property setting for the TextView or what?

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:text="Large Text" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

And my code:

```
public class AsyncTask1 extends Activity 
{
public TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_task1);
    this.txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

}

 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
    myAsync m = new myAsync(this);
     m.execute("");
 }

}
```

And here is my AsyncTask derivation:

```
class myAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    AsyncTask1 pld = null;
    public myAsync(AsyncTask1 pld)
    {
        this.pld = pld;
    }

    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... N) 
    {
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
            catch (Exception e) {}
            publishProgress();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) 
    {
             pld.txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call a method in the ui thread from onProgressUpdate and set your text from that method?

Comment: Good question! Interesting, but the same happens as I update my textview from the onClick itself... hm.

Answer (score 0):

invalidate function will redraw your view. `pld.txt.invalidate();`

Comment: Does not work :(

int cc = 1;
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  cc++;
  txt.setText(String.valueOf(cc));
  txt.invalidate();
}

Comment: Interestingly, when I delete the android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" from the manifest, it starts working in the good way... hm.

Comment: Still don't know the real reason of the problem. The theme is generated by the new project template in eclipse, 

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>